# web directories under /var/ or /home/username/?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, web

Can somebody advice on web directories under /var/ vs /home/username/? Or where else you normally put web directories?

What I can think of, /var is more natural since web serving is a site event and is the default. But under /home seems more secure because that doesn't need to turn on ftp chroot.

I am moving from single-user/single-site to multi-user/multi-site in a server, so this question becomes important.

Comment: `/var` should be used for the general web site, `/home/username/` for per-user web pages.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Both are feasible.

From the point of view of a web server, Apache for example, it doesn't matter what directory path is used to store each site files, as long as the web server and virtual host configuration files are correct.

A more important aspect, specially for security aspects, is related with permissions. This includes permissions for these users:

- The system user that runs the web server process, like for example *www* or *www-data*
- The owner and group associated to the directories and files of each site
- The other users of the system

If your scenario depends on personal web sites for one or more users, something like [Apache mod_userdir module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_userdir.html) could be helpful.

That's all for now.